# Update Django object field without refresh the page

Tags: python, django

How can I call a view function that change object field without refresh the page?

**views.py**

```
def add_like(request, pk):
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
    book.like = True
    book.save()
    return redirect('book_list')
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^add_like/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.add_like, name='add_like'),
```

**list.html**

```
[...]
<td><a href="{% url 'add_like' pk=book.pk %}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color: grey;"></span></a></td>
[...]
```

Once user click the button, I want to change like status and the  tag content to:

```
<td><a href="{% url 'remove_like' pk=book.pk %}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color: red;"></span></a></td>
```

I know Ajax can be the answer, but I don't know how to implement it.

Thanks.

Comment: An Ajax like approach is the only way *imho*

Comment: Ok, can you give me an example? I said I don't know how to do that :S

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`<td><a href="{% url 'remove_like' pk=book.pk %}" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" style="color: red;"></span></a></td>`

Use an input and give it an ID like

`<td><input style="color: red" class="book btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-heart" value="{book.pk}" /></td>`

Then according [with this example](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html) call the AJAX function

```
  <script>
    $(".book").on('click', function () {
      var id = $(this).val();

      $.ajax({
        url: '/add_like/',
        data: {
          'pk': id
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data) {
            alert(data);
          }
        }
      });

    });
  </script>
```

Then update your view with:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
def add_like(request):
    pk = request.GET.get('pk', None)
    book = Book.objects.get(pk=pk)
    book.like = True
    book.save()
    data = {'book', book}
    return JsonResponse('data')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but with this piece of code, I don't see the heart glyphicon; instead I see the book id number inside the input. Another thing is that the icon doesn't change its color if I don't refresh the page.